# Async in a small android game

Tags: android, android-asynctask

writing a small android game for a university assignment and just wanted to check what I'm doing is correct.

I'm creating a Mastermind type game and am unsure how to handle basic game operations such as checking if a guess is correct.

Am I correct in thinking that the best way to handle these operations is to create inner classes that extend Async to avoid UI lockup?

If not could anyone suggest any other ways?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a more specific question? Try writing this for yourself and ask again when you get stuck.

Comment: Anything thats going to block the main UI thread for a time should use a Async task yes.

Comment: @ethan I am quite confident in writing the code. I just wanted to get some input in my planning stage as to whether this was the best idea or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many weeks of developing my application, AsyncTask is what I used instead of standard threads. AyncTasks are less likely to get killed, they create a worker thread and handlers by themselves so you can update GUI through it more easily than standard threads. But remember that only one instance of AsyncTask can work at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need AsyncTask for this game at all. AsyncTask is a process for which you do not know how long it will take and you don't want to block your UI thread, like downloading something from Internet.

Your game can be completly events driven. Whenever the user makes a move you call your methods.
If you want to have animations while the user thinks then SurfaceView can do the job.